# Difference between these np dtypes

Tags: numpy

I have two questions concerning numpy dtypes:

(1) I have noticed that the following numpy datatypes compare equal but are not identical:

```
np.str_ == np.dtype('U') # true
id(np.str_) == id(np.dtype('U'))
```

Is there any difference between these types or are these just different ways of specifying the same type?

(2):

If I specify the following:

```
a = np.array([1,2,3],dtype='d')
b = np.array([1,2,3],dtype='g')
```

then I get the same array dtype

```
a.dtype
dtype('float64')
b.dtype
dtype('float64')
```

but the individual elements are different:

```
type(a[0])
<class 'numpy.float64'>
type(b[0])
<class 'numpy.longdouble'>
```

My question: What is the exact difference between these individual element types and why are they mapped to the same array type?

Comment: Ask your questions separately after reading the docs carefully and showing how they leave some room for your questions.

Comment: dtypes have lots of equivalencies and synonyms.  There should be a good documentation page. I'd stay away from testing `id`.  'U10' is a valid string dtype. 'U' or 'str_' is indeterminate on length, and generally not useful.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Comment: `np.str_` is a function that can be used like the python `str`.  `np.dtype('U')` is a `dtype` object; it is not callable.  But when used in `np,array('test', np.str_)` the result is the same. producing an array that displays as `array('test', dtype='<U4')`

Comment: Another useful documentation page, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html

Comment: Actually `np.str_` is a class (and thus has a callable `__init__`).  You can look at its `__mro__`.  Same for `np.float64` and `np.longdouble`.  Some of these classes have stronger ties to the underlying `C` implemenation.  Unless you have special needs, it's best to stick with the more general, portable, specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the floats:

```
In [174]: a = np.array([1.32,23.01,3],dtype='d')    
In [175]: b = np.array([1.32,23.01,3],dtype='g')
```

The underlying data-buffer is the same - viewing them as bytes:

```
In [176]: a.view('u1')
Out[176]: 
array([ 31, 133, 235,  81, 184,  30, 245,  63, 195, 245,  40,  92, 143,
         2,  55,  64,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   8,  64], dtype=uint8)

In [177]: b.view('u1')
Out[177]: 
array([ 31, 133, 235,  81, 184,  30, 245,  63, 195, 245,  40,  92, 143,
         2,  55,  64,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   0,   8,  64], dtype=uint8)

In [178]: a.dtype, b.dtype
Out[178]: (dtype('float64'), dtype('float64'))
```

On my machine (regular Windows 11), `longdouble` is the same as `double`; it doesn't support `float96` or `float128`.

While a `list` contains references to python objects, a numpy array has a 'raw' `c` array of bytes.  `a[0]` doesn't return the object in that array.  It returns a new python object, a `numpy scalar`, whose type is determined, in one or other, by the `dtype`, and value is 'copied' from the array.  This `unboxing` is more complicated than list indexing, and also slower.

```
In [179]: a[0], b[0]
Out[179]: (1.32, 1.32)    
In [180]: type(a[0]), type(b[0])
Out[180]: (numpy.float64, numpy.longdouble)
```

There's a complex class inheritance tree under these types

```
In [193]: type(a[0]).__mro__
Out[193]: 
(numpy.float64,
 numpy.floating,
 numpy.inexact,
 numpy.number,
 numpy.generic,
 float,
 object)

In [194]: type(b[0]).__mro__
Out[194]: 
(numpy.longdouble,
 numpy.floating,
 numpy.inexact,
 numpy.number,
 numpy.generic,
 object)
```

As documented on the `scalars` page, there are lots of `aliases`.